# C++ Passing function as parameter (between headers)

Tags: c++11

My problem is that I want to pass a header's function in another header's function as parameter, but i get an error I don't know what to do with.

header1:

```
class headerClass1{
public:
void funct1(){}
};
```

header2:

```
typedef void (*functCall)()

class headerClass2{
public:
void funct2(functCall fc()){}
};
```

main:

```
int main(){

headerClass1 *h1=new headerClass1(parameters);
headerClass2 *h2=new headerClass2(parameters);

h2->funct2(h1->funct1());
```

^returns error "invalid use of void expresion"

```
...
delete h1;
delete h2;
return 0;
}
```

Please go in to detail why this doesn't work.

Comment: There are too many basic errors. It will beneficial for you to go through a text book to understand the basics of the language correctly.

Comment: `h1->funct1()` is a call to funct1, `&h1->funct1` is the address of the function (which you need to pass). In headerClass2 your funct2's parameter should be changed to `void funct2(functCall fc)`. And then you still have the problem that your functions are member functions and not plain functions. It would be better if you describe what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You have several errors there.

To defining a function pointer to a member function must be done like this:

```
typedef void(headerClass1::*functCall)(void);
```

Then, you need an object to call this function pointer upon. Here is a working example:

```
class headerClass1
{
public:
   void funct1() 
   {
      std::cout << "funct1" << std::endl;
   }
};

typedef void(headerClass1::*functCall)(void);

class headerClass2 
{
public:
   void funct2(headerClass1& o, functCall fn)
   {
      std::cout << "funct2" << std::endl;
      (o.*fn)();
   }
};

int main()
{
   headerClass1 c1;
   headerClass2 c2;

   c2.funct2(c1, &headerClass1::funct1);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you specified pointer to function not to class method.
And as parameter you just post function result which is void.
You need a method pointer plus an object pointer.

void funct2(void (headerClass1 ::*pMethod)(), headerClass1 * pObject);

h2->funct2(&headerClass1:funct1, h1);

call inside funct2 :
(*pObject.*pMethod)();